Vue lite table not displaying slot
I am using the VueTableLite from vue3-table-lite/ts package and am running into an issue where I am unable to get the below table to update when using a v-slot
<script setup lang="ts">
import vueTable from '@/components/plugins/VueTable.vue' // This file is where I use the plugin
import { onMounted, reactive } from 'vue'

onMounted(async () => {
    doSearch(0, 10, 'id', 'asc')
})

const doSearch = (offset, limit, order, sort) => {
    table.isLoading = true
    ...
}


// Table config
const table = reactive({
    isLoading: false,
    columns: [
        {
            label: 'ID',
            field: 'id',
            width: '10%',
            sortable: true,
            isKey: true,
        },
                ...
        {
            label: 'Active',
            field: 'active',
            width: '15%',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            label: 'Actions',
            field: 'actions',
            width: '15%',
            sortable: false,
        },
    ],
    rows: [],
    totalRecordCount: 0,
    sortable: {
        order: 'id',
        sort: 'asc',
    },
})


</script>


Now for the template
<template>
<vue-table class="vue-table"
    :has-checkbox="false"
    :isSlotMode="true"
    :is-loading="table.isLoading"
    :columns="table.columns"
    :rows="table.rows"
    :total="table.totalRecordCount"
    :sortable="table.sortable"
    @is-finished="table.isLoading = false"
  >

        <template v-slot:active="data">
            {{ data.value.active ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
        </template>

    </vue-table>
</template>

I was expecting the "active" column in the table to display the work "Yes" when true and "No" when false. Instead it dispays the actual true/false value.
Example row
{
        "id": "05c46aa8-5a07-4f98-a0b0-bafb84f69703",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastLogin": "2024-09-20T11:48:30.611Z",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "role": "ADMIN",
        "createdAt": "2024-08-13T02:49:36.220Z",
        "active": true
    }

VueTable.vue
<script>
import VueTableLite from 'vue3-table-lite/ts'

export default {
    components: {
        VueTableLite,
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <vue-table-lite />
</template>


Please, provide a way to reproduce. The lib isn't popular, and the users cannot be expected to have knowledge that allows to solve this on paper. From what I see, it could be workable, it's unknown what "rows" are in your case. I see no explanation why boolean value could appear instead of a string

@EstusFlask I don't have a way of reproducing it outside the code base. "rows" is just the data for the table. It does come back with "active" as a boolean not a string. That has to do with the data structure and how it is stored in my database. I will add an example row in my post.

Consider providing it to solve the problem. This needs to be debugged. What you describe looks like this setting.isSlotMode && slots[col.field] condition here https://github.com/linmasahiro/vue3-table-lite/blob/master/src/components/TableLiteTs.vue#L148 is false and {{ data.value.active ? 'Yes' : 'No' }} doesn't affect anything, I don't see why it could be so

Can you post your vueTable component? It is possible that the slot you are trying to reference, is going to your custom .vue file, and not the actual plugin.

@m4el added that to the main post

@joshk132 have you tried changing :isSlotMode="true" to :is-slot-mode="true", and embracing the condition in another component? Like <span> {{ data.value.active ? 'Yes' : 'No' }} </span>

Tried the component the way you sugested, and it seems to work just fine.

@m4el That is really odd, any ideas why it might work in your case but not mine? Stabs in the dark are good with me.

If its not a requirement to use this package as a plugin, try importing it directly in your component and using it as is.

@joshk132 What you have is the reason why reproducible code is required by SO rules. This prevents wasting everyone's time on "It doesn't work", "No, it does" kind of interaction
